# Upgraded a virtual guest system: /dev/disk/uuid... does not exit

Tags: boot, grub2, upgrade, kernel, virtualbox

I recently upgraded my Ubuntu 14.04 (kubuntu), running as a guest inside VirtualBox 4.3.12 hosted by Windows 7 Enterprise, 64 bit.

All ran fine until yesterday - when I tried to start the new upgraded system.

First is that the new system (kernel 3.13.0-52-generic) won't boot: I get the classic

```
ALERT!  /dev/disk/by-uuid/<long string> does not exist.  Dropping to a shell!
```

error and I'm dropped into the `(initramfs)` prompt of ash.  I can boot an older system (kernel 3.13.0-32-generic), but it provides a sort of  broken KDE in which the window manager seems not to start: an app will start, and be plonked into the upper left of the (one)desktop, with no capability of moving it, or re-sizing it.  And there are no options in any of the system setting menus for adding more virtual desktops.

I've a lot of web searching about this - which is an error I've never seen before - but I'm not sure how to apply fixes to a virtual system.  I suppose I could simply install a completely new system from scratch... but is that the best way?  Note that `blkid` currently returns as its only line

```
/dev/sr0: LABEL="VBOXADDITIONS_4.3.12_93733" TYPE="iso9660"
```

Also, there isn't a `/dev/disk` directory, nor is there a `/boot` directory.  A while back I did manage to get lines from `blkid` including the boot image in `/dev/sda1`  but I'm not sure where it's gone now.

I've tried: transferring my linux virtual image ("ubuntu.vdi") to a SCSI controller in VirtualBox, adding the parameter "rootdelay=60" to the boot line in the GRUB menu, but so far nothing's worked.

Any help would be very gratefully received, as I need my Linux for most of my work, and it has to run inside Windows as my institution uses Microsoft AD for everything, including accessing common drives and printers.  And our IT services refuse point blank to build in Linux support.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem on a physical machine. It looks like it had rebooted during an update, and had left grub booting a kernel image (3.13.0-45-generic) that was unable to find my hard drives, and didn't have an entry for /dev/disk/by-uuid/.

I solved the problem by booting from an older kernel, and then completing the upgrade. This gave me 3.13.0-53-generic, which seems to work better.

1) Boot to the grub prompt, press 'e' to view the boot script for the current (broken) boot process. Take a photo of the screen.
2) Press ESC, then 'c' to get to the GRUB command prompt.
3) Check the contents of the boot directory on your root drive, to see what kernels you have available. (Replace hd0,msdos3 with whatever your root is):

```
grub> ls (hd0,msdos3)/boot/
grub/ .... vmlinuz-3.13.0-45-generic vmlinuz-3.2.0-70-generic initrd.img-3.13.0-45-generic initrd.img-3.2.0-70-generic
```

4) Boot from the older kernel. (Refer to your photo for the exact commands and the root UUID=... . Use tab-completion to get the spelling exactly right, and use the same version number for vmlinuz and initrd.img):

```
grub> set root='hd0,msdos3'
grub> linux /boot/vmlinuz-3.2.0-70-generic root=UUID=xxx[replace this]xx ro
grub> initrd /boot/initrd.img-3.2.0-70-generic
grub> boot
```

(It may take a few tries to get everything right. If the UUID doesn't work, try root=/dev/sda3 -- or whatever Linux calls your root disk+partition.)